# TypeScript: check key in object / narrowing at runtime

Tags: typescript

I have the following (almost) JavaScript code that works as intended:

```
const config = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  default: 3
}

const getConfig = (key: string) => {
  return config[key] || config.default
}
```

However, in TypeScript gives me of course an error, because not any kind of string is a valid index of `config`.

But the following unfortunately doesn't work either:

```
const getConfig = (key: string) => {
  return key in config
    ? config[key]
    : config.default
}
```

See [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYDMCWBzGBeGBvAUDGAhgFwwCMANHjAEYkBMl+AJgKYIECuANlCQMw4AvjhzxoMFCygBhcMjSYAFAGsWATxLQATkjAoAlBgB82KlqkctYGKrUxdcOair4A-I8SoA2rYC6LmBJ4eQA6VnZuKCERSRknFEUAcgJE-RxY2U8ExOBUoA).

Is there a way to construct some kind of [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates) or what would you recommend? Do I really have to do `config as any`? That would seem silly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution where you will have the type inference.

Beware, I will be using the ugly `as any` but I am typing the function so it is not visible when you use the `getConfig` function.

```
type Config = (typeof config)['default'] // just number in this case

const getConfig = (key: string): Config => {
  return (config as any)[key] || config.default
}
```

Or for different config values:

```
const config = {
  a: 1,
  b: "yo",
  default: {
    something: true
  }
}

type Config = typeof config;

type ConfigKey = keyof Config;

const getConfig = <K extends string>(key: K): K extends ConfigKey ? Config[K] : Config['default'] => {
  return (config as any)[key]  || config.default
}

const ofTypeNumber = getConfig('a')
const ofTypeString = getConfig('b')
const ofTypeDefaultConfig = getConfig('c')
```

Comment: thanks, I ended up doing something similar and edited in your answer. feel free to edit again :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can give a type to your config object - `{ [key:string]: number }`

```
const config: { [key:string]: number } = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  default: 3
}
```

And then you can get any value from the object by `string` key.

You can make this type a little more generic, for example

```
type Map<T> = {
  [key: string] : T
}
```

For index key you can use `number` as well.

Comment: I would also suggest on top of this that we give the type a name, that way it can be reuse everywhere in the application.

Comment: thanks! yes I see... well, in practice, the config json is a bit more elaborate than `number`... it was nice that it inferred the complex type automatically... but yes, I suppose I can rewrite it somehow...

Answer (score 1):

You can use record to achieve that:

```js
const config: Record<string, number> = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  default: 3
}

const getConfig = (key: string) => {
  return key in config
    ? config[key]
    : config.default
}

getConfig('a')
getConfig('c')
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=15#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYDMCWBzAXDASgU1AJwBMAeaPJMFAGhjAFcBbAI2zwD4YBeGAbwCgYYAQwwBGSvxiMMAJnECC2BINoAbKBgDMvAL69e8aDBTYoAYXDIUnGAAoA1tgCeGUuRQBKTuz4C8J2nhgMA6OMORwFqgSAgD8EYioANohALrRMBjwlgB0CkqqUDp6xmaRKDYA5IIV7rwl5gnlFcA1QA)

Comment: thanks! but now `const n = config['c']` has type `number` as well... so I'm trading one kind of evil `config as any` against this one..? (also see my comment on the other answer)